# How do I display an error message in an MVC5 Delete post. Have searched but cant find anything on Delete

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to catch a record dependency error on an attempted delete to avoid the grey death. Below works but does not display the error.

Using ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "message") works fine in Create post but not in Delete post.

Any help would be appreciated.

Part of Controller

```
 // POST: Divisions/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [DbFunction]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var division = await _context.Division.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Division.Remove(division);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Cannot Delete. Associated Records Exist");
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Delete));
    }
```

Part of Delete View

```
<form asp-action="Delete">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Division1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to Use TempData to display a message on view. Store your message in TempData and display it on view.

Comment: If you add a `ModelState`, you need to return the view, not redirect. Once you redirect, `ModelState` is lost

Comment: Thank you Stephen, changing return RedirectToAction(nameof(Delete)); to return View(division); gave me an error but a simple return View(); works. I like simple answers. Being a newbe I don't quite understand why View(division); gives an error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a ModelState, you need to return the view, not redirect. Once you redirect, ModelState is lost.

Use         return View();

Not         return redirectToAction(nameof(Index));
Not         return View(xxxxxxx);